# TypeError (0x800a01a8): Object required: 'Document'

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

i have a classic asp page with inside the following vbscript 
but it say that the Document object dose not exist why??

```
TypeError (0x800a01a8): Object required: 'Document'
```

the vbscript code:

```
<script language="vbscript" RUNAT="Server">
Function getDescriptionEstProc()
    Dim  CONNECTSTRING, QUALIFIER, QueryDescEstProc, dbConnect, res,output, param

    CONNECTSTRING = Session("CONNECTSTRING")
    QUALIFIER = Session("QUALIFIER")

    param = PageParams1.UIDMeterHistory

    QueryDescEstProc = "select e.description from meterhistory mh, meterread m, estimationprocess e where m.uidestproc = e.uidestproc  and m.uidmeter = mh.uidmeter and mh.uidmeterhistory = '"& "0100001" &"'"

    Set dbConnect = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rsWQType = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    dbConnect.Open CONNECTSTRING

    rsWQType.Open QueryDescEstProc, dbConnect

    res = ""

    Do While Not rsWQType.EOF 
        res = res & rsWQType("description") & ","
    Loop

    Dim TheForm 
    Set TheForm = Document.forms("Form1")
    TheForm.hiddenString.Value = res

    Response.Write res & " - hello"

    getDescriptionEstProc = res


    End Function
</script>
```

(there is no aspx file)
the .asp file:

```
  <form name="Form1" method="post" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode==13) {this.submit();event.returnValue=false;} else event.returnValue=true;">
<input class="lookup" type=hidden name="Id" value="<%=PageParams1.Id%>">
<input type=hidden name="SessionId" value="<%=PageParams1.SessionId%>">
<input type=hidden name="Command" value="">
<input type=hidden name="AccountID" value="<%=PageParams1.AccountID%>">
<input type=hidden name="UIDFACILITY" value="<%=PageParams1.UIDFACILITY%>">
<input type=hidden name="FACILITYID" value="<%=PageParams1.FACILITYID%>">
<input type=hidden name="METERID" value="<%=PageParams1.METERID%>">
<input type=hidden name="UIDMETER" value="<%=PageParams1.UIDMETER%>">
<input type=hidden name="UIDMeterHistory" value="<%=PageParams1.UIDMeterHistory%>">
<input type=hidden name="CustomerName" value="<%=PageParams1.CustomerName%>">
<input type=hidden name="CustomerId" value="<%=PageParams1.CustomerId%>">
<input type=hidden name="EntityParam" value="<%=PageParams1.EntityParam%>">
<input type=hidden name="SORT_BY" value="<%=PageParams1.SORT_BY%>"> 
<input type=hidden name="SORT_ORDER" value="<%=PageParams1.SORT_ORDER%>">
<input type=hidden name="Mode" value="<%=PageParams1.Mode%>">
    <table class="SnapIn" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border=0><tr class="ToolsTabs">
  <td class="Title"><nobr><%=Proxy1.i18n.FM("MeterHistory")%></nobr></td>
  <td class="ToolsLeft">
    <b><%=Proxy1.i18n.FM("ID")%></b> &nbsp; <%=meterId %>
        <%if (PageParams1.Mode == "ServicePoint") {%>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../../ccs/MainWebPart.aspx?Mode=
  <%=PageParams1.Mode%>&SessionId=<%=PageParams1.SessionId%>&Uid=
  <%=Proxy1.Session.GetPropertyValue("SERVICEPOINT_UID")%>">
  <%=Proxy1.i18n.FM("ServicePointSummary")%></a>
    <% } else if (PageParams1.Mode == "MarketParticipant") { %>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../../ccs/MainWebPart.aspx?Mode=
  <%=PageParams1.Mode%>&SessionId=<%=PageParams1.SessionId%>&Uid=
  <%=Proxy1.Session.GetPropertyValue("MARKETPARTICIPANT_UID")%>">
  <%=Proxy1.i18n.FM("MarketParticipantSummary")%></a>
    <% } %>
  </td>
  <td class="ToolsRight"><nobr>&nbsp;
        <%if (PageParams1.AccountID) {%>
      <b><%=Proxy1.i18n.FM("AccountID")%></b>
      <a class="Link" onclick='window.navigate("../viewaccount/Meters.asp?Id=<%= escape(PageParams1.AccountID)%>&SessionId=<%=PageParams1.SessionId%>")'><u><%=PageParams1.AccountID %></u></a>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <%} if (PageParams1.CustomerId) {%>
    <b><%=Proxy1.i18n.FM("CustomerID")%></b>
      <a class='Link' onclick='navigate("../../ccs/MainWebPart.aspx?Id=<%=escape(PageParams1.CustomerId)%>&SessionId=<%=PageParams1.SessionId%>"+"&Mode=Customer")'> 
          <%=PageParams1.CustomerId%>
      </a>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <%} if (PageParams1.UIDFACILITY) {%>
        <b><%=Proxy1.i18n.FM("FacilityID")%></b>
        <a class=Link onclick='navigate("../cust_facility/Basics.asp?UIDFACILITY=<%=PageParams1.UIDFACILITY%>&SessionId=<%=PageParams1.SessionId%>&X_ROWPERPAGE=50")'>
            <%=PageParams1.FACILITYID%>
        </a>
      <%}%>
  </nobr></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td class="TabBox" colspan="3"><%= RenderTabs("MeterRead") %></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td class="Body" colspan="3">
    <%          if (OperationError) ReportError(OperationError)%>

    <%if (PageParams1.Command=='Edit') { %>
            <table width=100%><tr><td class=LinkBox>
              <%if (Proxy1.Allow("//ACCTMGT/ACCTCOMP/ACCTMET/@UPDATE")) {%>
              <a href="javascript: Save()"><%=Proxy1.i18n.FM("Save")%></a> |
              <%}%>
              <%if (PageParams1.EntityParam && Proxy1.Allow("//ACCTMGT/ACCTCOMP/ACCTMET/@REMOVE") ) { %><a href="javascript: Delete()"><%=Proxy1.i18n.FM("Delete")%></a> |<% } %>
              <a href="javascript: Cancel()"><%=Proxy1.i18n.FM("Cancel")%></a>
            </td></tr></table>
    <%} else%>
        <%=tMeterHistoryTable %>

    <%if (PageParams1.Command != 'Edit') { %>
        <table style="width: expression(Math.max(document.body.offsetWidth-55, 540))">
        <tr>
        <td align=left>
        <%
                    if (Proxy1.Allow("//FACILITY/ADD"))
                    {
                %>
                                <a href="javascript: Edit()" ><%=Proxy1.i18n.FM("Add")%></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <%
                    }
                    if (Proxy1.Allow("//FACILITY/REEST_ACTION/@REESTIMATE")) { %>
                                <a href="javascript: reestimate()">Ristima</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <%
                    }
                    if (Proxy1.Allow("//FACILITY/REEST_ACTION_2")) { %>
                                <a href="javascript: reestimate2()">Ristima lettura conferimento</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <%  }
                    if (Proxy1.Allow("//FACILITY/REEST_ACTION/@DISCHARGE")) { %>
                                <a href="javascript: discharge()">Scarta</a>
                <%  } %>
                            </td>
                            <!--Indicazione righe e pagina-->
                            <td align=right>
                            <%= Paginator_b(PageParams1.ROWPERPAGE, PageParams1.PAGENUMBER) %>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
            <%
                } 
            %>
<div class="mAppScroll" style="height:100% width:100%"><% =tTable %></div>
<tr>
                        <td>
                            <!--Cannata Alberto - modifica del 09/10/2006: aggiorniamo i campi LSUSER e LSTIME della METERHISTORY.-->
                            <input type="hidden" name = "OLD_STATUS" value = "<%=oldstatus_str%>">
                            <input type="hidden" name = "X_LSUSER" value = "<%=username_web.toUpperCase()%>">
                            <input type="hidden" name = "X_LSTIME" value = "<%=data_modifica%>">
                        </td>
</tr>
</td>
</tr>
</table><!-- /SnapIn -->
<input type="hidden" id="hiddString" name="hiddenString" value="">
<% 
    getDescriptionEstProc();
%>

<SCRIPT language="javascript">
    appendColumn();
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hk29wbb7(v=vs.84).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Document.Forms is not used in server-side `ASP`, it's used in client-side code such as `Javascript` and `VBScript`.  If you are trying to post data with your form, look into using Request["fieldname"] to get the values you need.

It looks like you're just trying to set the value of the hidden field?

Since the function returns the value you want (res), just do this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddString" name="hiddenString" value="<%=getDescriptionEstProc()%>">
```

Hope this helps.

Good luck.

Comment: do you think this is javascript ?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hk29wbb7(v=vs.84).aspx

Comment: Hi @frank -- not sure who down voted you.  Wasn't me -- I wouldn't down vote someone and then answer their question.  BTW -- in the above link, Document is used as client-side code (just as if it were being used with Javascript), while you were attempting to use it as server-side code (runat=server).  Good luck.